# Have camera follow player -object position and rotation in 3D-space (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

My objective here is to have a smoothed out "follow camera", for my space-fighter proof of concept game. The camera should match roll off the target object in all  axis.

To that end I've "stolen" and modified this code from the unity Answers-site, and it works beautifully for X and Y (pitch and yaw), but it refuses to roll.

Code:

```
public float Distance;
public float Height;
public float RotationDamping;
public GameObject Target;

void LateUpdate()
{
    var wantedRotationAngleYaw = Target.transform.eulerAngles.y;
    var currentRotationAngleYaw = transform.eulerAngles.y;

    var wantedRotationAnglePitch = Target.transform.eulerAngles.x;
    var currentRotationAnglePitch = transform.eulerAngles.x;

    var wantedRotationAngleRoll = Target.transform.eulerAngles.z;
    var currentRotationAngleRoll = transform.eulerAngles.z;

    currentRotationAngleYaw = Mathf.LerpAngle(currentRotationAngleYaw, wantedRotationAngleYaw, RotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);

    currentRotationAnglePitch = Mathf.LerpAngle(currentRotationAnglePitch, wantedRotationAnglePitch, RotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);

    currentRotationAngleRoll = Mathf.LerpAngle(currentRotationAngleRoll, wantedRotationAngleRoll, RotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);

    var currentRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotationAnglePitch, currentRotationAngleYaw, currentRotationAngleRoll);

    transform.position = Target.transform.position;
    transform.position -= currentRotation * Vector3.forward * Distance;

    transform.LookAt(Target.transform);
    transform.position += transform.up * Height;
}
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be more certain about this answer if you explained what you were trying to do, but you should consider moving by `Height` in the direction of `currentRotation * Vector3.up` instead of `transform.up`. Also, consider using `currentRotation * Vector3.up` to set the local up direction when calling `LookAt`:

```
transform.position = Target.transform.position;
transform.position -= currentRotation * Vector3.forward * Distance;

Vector3 currentUp = currentRotation * Vector3.up;
transform.LookAt(Target.transform, currentUp);
transform.position += currentUp * Height;
```

Comment: I've added a better description of my goal, but the important part is: "My objective here is to have a smoothed out "follow camera""

Comment: I'll try out your suggestion. I'll let you know in a couple of hours if it's what I need

Comment: @FrankR.Haugen Alright. It sounds like you're also trying to make the camera's axes smoothly align with the axes of the target. I changed my answer to account for that.

Comment: Spot on! This now works exactly the way it should. Thank you very much!